# textFieldShouldReturn doesn't work (using storyboard on XCode 4)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a button and a textfield. I just want keyboard disappear when clicking on button. Why my code below doesn't work.

Update: I saw something about file owner. I don't understand how to do this in XCode4 I use storyboard and I can't see any file owner icon.

Update 2: I found a tut http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Writing_iOS_4_Code_to_Hide_the_iPhone_Keyboard_%28Xcode_4%29 but it uses XIB file on XCode 4 not storyboard. How to do this with storyboard ?

myViewController.h

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    UITextField *myTextField;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
```

myViewController.m

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn: (UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myTextField.delegate = self;
}

- (IBAction)DoCalc:(id)sender {
      // ...
}
```

Comment: As textField is created in IB. Is it connected with the myTextField reference. Also, myTtextField has one extra character 'T' in it.

Comment: Thanks I fixed the T but problem of hiding keyboard is nit linked to it :)

Answer (score 5):

Check to see if the textFieldShouldReturn function that you've written into myViewController.m is even being called. Set a breakpoint inside of it and then run the simulator. Press the return key on the keyboard. If the program doesn't break, then the function you've written isn't being called.

If it is, it's because you haven't delegated UIResponder duties to your view controller. Make sure you are delegating responder duties to your myViewController class for the UITextField that you're working with.

In storyboard, you do this by control-dragging from the UITextField widget to the yellow orb below the scene, and selecting "delegate" from the context menu that appears.

Answer (score 3):

`textFieldShouldReturn:` should return NO to hide the keyboard. One more thing - do not set first responder to `self`, `[textField resignFirstResponder]` is enough, iOS should figure `nextResponder` by itself.

Comment: Thanks I tried but it still doesn't work another suggestion ? :)

Comment: If you have `textFieldShouldEndEditing:` method implemented, it should return YES.

Comment: No I didn't implement textFieldShouldEndEditing

Comment: Update: I saw something about file owner. I don't understand how to do this in XCode4 I use storyboard and I can't see any file owner icon.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the keybord in this method...

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

     [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Thanks I also tried but it still doesn't work either another suggestion ? :)

Comment: did you set the textfield delegate ?

Comment: weather this method is calling for you ?

Comment: Update: I saw something about file owner. I don't understand how to do this in XCode4 I use storyboard and I can't see any file owner icon.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `[self becomeFirstResponder];` should do it.

`resignFirstResponder` is to dismiss the keyboard. while `becomeFirstResponder` is to open the keyboard. so in your code, you are closing then opening again the keyboard at the same time. The last action is opened the keyboard, hence it won't close.

you may look into [UIResponder Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/resignFirstResponder) as superclass of `UITextField`

Comment: True I removed it (I followed a tut which said to do so). Still it doesn't make it.

Comment: Update: I saw something about file owner. I don't understand how to do this in XCode4 I use storyboard and I can't see any file owner icon.

Comment: I think `textFieldShouldReturn` is not even called. you should check your `UITextField` link in storyboard.

Comment: What do you mean by "link" ? Sorry I'm very beginner.

Comment: connect `UITextField` to `IBOutlet` in File Owner.