# Why XCode 4 doesn't create XIB file when using storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

Why can't XCode 4 create XIB file while using storyboard: is it 2 incompatible models ? For example all tutorials about hiding keyboards seem to require XIB file:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Writing_iOS_4_Code_to_Hide_the_iPhone_Keyboard_%28Xcode_4%29

Comment: Can you give an example of keyboard hiding that we can update to storybaord?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question because I couldn't find any example, I only found with XIB file http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Writing_iOS_4_Code_to_Hide_the_iPhone_Keyboard_%28Xcode_4%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an update to the link in the question:

> Having written the code for our method we now need to wire up our user interface so that it gets called at the appropriate time. We will perform this task in Interface Builder, so select hideKeyboardViewController.xib once more.

The equivalent of this now is to click on storyboard, and then click the hidKeyboardViewController in the storybaord window.

> Select the text field in the view and display the Connections Inspector (View -> Utilities -> Connections Inspector) in the right hand panel.

The equivalent of this now is to Right click the text field.

> Click on the circle to the right of the Did End on Exit event, drag the line to the File’s Owner icon and select textFieldReturn from the list of available methods.

Equivalent here is to click the circle, as mentioned, then drag the blue line to the orange box at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Its the same, inside the storyboard you will see your views and you can do the same as you did when you were working directly with .xibs

Answer (score 1):

**Treat the "scenes" in the storyboard as if they were XIBs**. You can layout the screen, add elements, and link them up to their respective ViewControllers. Any code you need to run should be in a ViewController, and then in the Storyboard you can indicate that a particular scene is related to that ViewController.

For your question about hiding the keyboard, you'll need to have a method in your ViewController that includes a line of code:

```
[myTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

...where myTextField is a UITextField, UITextView, or other object that requires a keyboard.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518281/textfieldshouldreturn-doesnt-work